# Why my comupter is showing two different architectures on excuting two different commands?

Tags: ubuntu, x86-64, intel

I am using Intel chip set motherboard with i3 Processor. I have installed ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso since it is only readily available (I believe, there is no specific build called x86_64).

I executed **lscpu** and **dpkg --print-architecture** in terminal. First one is giving architecture as **x86_64** and later is showing **amd64**.

I guess **amd64** and **x86_64** are internal architecture of cpu or is it the architecture of **OS**?.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601553/what-is-the-difference-between-x86-64-amd64-and-64-bit

Comment: @rkosegi - Thank you - Really it helps